# PHP array extract a particular key value from various arrays?

Tags: php

I have the following arrays

```
$country["china"] = array(
  "shortcode" => "CN",
  "president" => "Xi Jinping",
  "currency" => "Yuan",
  );

$country["america"] = array(
  "shortcode" => "US",
  "president" => "Barack Obama",
  "currency" => "Dollar",
  );

$country["russia"] = array(
  "shortcode" => "RU",
  "president" => "Vladimir Putin",
  "currency" => "Rubble",
  );
```

Now I'd like to extract the "president" value for each array above.

I tried this

```
foreach(array_keys($country) as $countryName => $countryvalue)
  echo  $countryvalue . "<br>";
```

I would like instead to get this output
Xi Jinping
Barack Obama
Vladimir Putin

but instead I am getting a list of countries.

Comment: Don't use `array_keys` then. Just a `foreach($country as $countrydata) echo $countrydata['president']`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
foreach($country as $c)
{
  echo $c["president"]."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($country as $countryName => $countryvalue){
   echo $val["president"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$country["china"] = array(
  "shortcode" => "CN",
  "president" => "Xi Jinping",
  "currency" => "Yuan",
  );

$country["america"] = array(
  "shortcode" => "US",
  "president" => "Barack Obama",
  "currency" => "Dollar",
  );

$country["russia"] = array(
  "shortcode" => "RU",
  "president" => "Vladimir Putin",
  "currency" => "Rubble",
  );


foreach($country as $key=>$val){
    echo $val["president"];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
foreach($country as $key => $value) {
       echo $value['president']."<br/>";

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly suggest you, to put all of that in database and access the data with simple query.

```
// Your table
CREATE TABLE `country`
(
    id serial primary key
    , name varchar(64)
    , shortcode varchar(2)
    , president varchar(64)
    , currency varchar(24)
);

// Insert data
INSERT INTO `country`
    ( name, shortcode, president, currency )
VALUES
    ( 'china', 'CN', 'Xi Jinping', 'Yuan' )
    , ( 'america', 'US', 'Barack Obama', 'Dollar' )
    , ( 'russia', 'RU', 'Vladimir Putin', 'Rubble' );
```

And now to access, just write simple query:

```
SELECT president FROM country WHERE name = 'china';
```

PS: this way it will be easier to update the data and you won't need to change your code.

Comment: Thanks but its small amount of data. So there is no need to stay diving int tables.

Comment: Don't say that. Data, that is permanent, should be in DB. Arrays are mostly used for generated data and **not** for storing information.